# I can't seem to execute an exe created in FoxPro unless I'm calling it from the main Window, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: build, executable, exe, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have a simple vfp project with one program (ppp), and one form (ppp). The form is an empty form, and the progran contains this:

```
SET DELETED ON 
SET DATE TO DMY 
SET SAFETY OFF 
_screen.visible=.F. 

DO FORM ppp

READ events
RETURN
```

I build the project to an .exe using the project manager and no errors appear, and I can execute the .exe from the main FoxPro window without any problem.

However, when I double-click the exe from Windows nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

By default the **ShowWindow** property of a form is set to **0 - In Screen**.  This means that the form is shown in the main VFP screen.  However, _screen.visible=.F. hides the screen so you can't see the VFP screen, or your form.

You can set _screen.visible=.T., but you'll see the main VFP screen, with your form in it, which you may not want.

You can also set the **ShowWindow** property of your form to **2 - As Top-Level Form**, which means it will display outside the VFP screen and on the windows taskbar.  In that case, you'll still see your form even if you hide the VFP screen with _screen.visible=.f.

[ShowWindow property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0ea0kz8(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: For some reason this didn't work, even if I set _streen.visible to .T. and ShowWindow as 2 the form doesn't open unless I open it from the main VFP window.

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is without seeing your project.   You can try setting the WindowType of your form to 1 - Modal, which means that it will block execution of your main program until the form is released.  Just make sure you have a button on the form that calls Thisform.Release() to close the form.

Answer (score 1):

You need vfp9r.dll and vfp9renu.dll in the exe path unless you have vfp installation.

Answer (score 1):

I have to learn VFP because I want to move to my company's development sector and they have some products written in VFP, eventually I got stuck into this problem too.
But I found the way to do it properly.

You need to initialize the event processing loop like this.

```
DO FORM ppp
READ EVENTS
```

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975719(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975719%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[Note] Sorry about my bad english, I am Brazilian.